# Prove that if $X,Y$ are independent, then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, where $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is differentiable and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is continuous.

Tags: statistics

> Prove that if $X,Y$ are independent absolutely continuous random variables, then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, at all points where $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is differentiable and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is continuous.

By definition of independence is $P(X\in A, Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$

So I believe I have:

$P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)=F_X(y)F_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)dy$

And I would also have:

$P(X\in A, Y\in B)=F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$

So I want that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$

But I'm not sure what allows me to conclude that?

Is what I'm trying to prove this statement?

if $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is differentiable and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is continuous then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ independent means $F_{XY}(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$.  The existences of the density functions and their relationship depend on theory of calculus, specifically, absolute continuity of $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$.  Probability theory is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=P(X\leq x) P(Y\leq y)$. This gives $\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{X,Y} (u,v)dudv=(\int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(u)du) (\int_{-\infty} ^{y}f_Y(v)dv$. If you differentiate w.r.t. $x$ and $y$  you get $F_{X,Y} (x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ by FTC.

Comment: Are the conditions of $F_{X,Y}$ being differentiable and $f_{X,Y}$ being continuous just what is required for FTC?

Comment: @AColoredReptile Yes, you need continuity of $f_{XY}$  to apply FTC. If $f_{XY}$ is continuous then $F_{XY}$ is automatically differentiable.